# strong parameters for related record not perceived for save action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A controller action invokes the update or creation of a record, while having a private method to set the strong params for that object's class, which is different from the originating class.

```
  def userdiscount
    articlediscount_params = params[:articlediscount]
    initialise_article_and_params(articlediscount_params)
puts articlediscount_params
    if articlediscount_params[:id].present?
      @articlediscount = Articlediscount.find(articlediscount_params[:id].to_i)
      @articlediscount.update!(articlediscount_params)
    else
      @articlediscount = Articlediscount.create!(articlediscount_params)
    end
  end

    def articlediscount_params
      params.require(:articlediscount).permit(:article_id, :user_id, :discounted_price, :discount, :shop_id)
    end
```

*The strong params definition is identical to the one in the articlediscounts controller*

Why then are tests complaining about the attributes?  *removing the `require` element of the statement does not modify the error*

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is this line:

```rb
articlediscount_params = params[:articlediscount]
```

The problem is that you now have two objects in this controller called `articlediscount_params` - this variable and the method that's actually doing your strong-params filtering. Remove the variable definition and you should find that your code works more as you expect.